# Validate a field using regex

Tags: regex, symfony, validation, annotations, doctrine

I want to validate the user data , I have a field budget and I want this format to be given ddd.ddd,ddd **exp : 235.123,125**

How can I specify this format with regex , I am using symfony and doctrine this what I have tried  and nothing happened when I have given a different format

```
/**
 * @var float
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="budget", type="float",nullable=true)
 *
 *
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *     pattern="/^\d\d\d[.]\d\d\d[,]\d\d\d+$/",
 *     match=false,
 *     message="Budget Invalid"
 * )
 */
private $budget;
```

Comment: you can try this: (\d{3}.\d{3},\d{3}) . Regards

Comment: That won't work @Albeis, you didn't escape the period

Comment: Which period? Regards @JasonRoman

Comment: The only one in your regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following fix:

```
* @Assert\Regex(
*     pattern="/^\d{3}\.\d{3},\d{3}$/",
*     match=true,
*     message="Budget Invalid"
```

Your pattern should *match* the format you specified, thus, [**`match`**](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Regex.html#match) must be set to *true*, or removed as *true* is the default value.

> If `true` (or not set), this validator will pass if the given string matches the given [pattern](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Regex.html#pattern) regular expression. However, when this option is set to `false`, the opposite will occur: validation will pass only if the given string does **not** match the [pattern](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Regex.html#pattern) regular expression.

The pattern can be shrunk a bit tot `^\d{3}\.\d{3},\d{3}$`: start of string, 3 digits, `.`, 3 digits, `,` and then 3 digits at the end of the string.

If the last number can have more than 3 digits, use `\d{3,}` instead of `\d{3}`.

Comment: I have tried it worked but my problem now is: I have a formcomposed of  2 tabs ,the budget is on the second tab and the validation fire an error after the validation of the first tab so I think I should javascript instead of validate in the annotation

Comment: @Julie That sounds like a different issue, doesn't it? Anyway, in JS, you just need to test the value with `/^\d{3}\.\d{3},\d{3}$/.test(your_string)`.